# What is identity mapping in neural networks

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I came across the term *identity mapping* in some papers about neural networks but am not sure what it is supposed to mean in that context.
I'm guessing it means to map a sort of input to an output?

I came across this term in the papers [*Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition* (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf) and [*Identity Mappings in Deep Residual Networks* (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05027.pdf), both by He et al.

Comment: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an neural network expert but I understand that identity mapping ensures that the output of some multilayer neural net is ensured to be equal to its input.  Such a net is also called a replicator.

I have understood that such identity/replication facilitates unsupervised training, and that the hidden layers of such nets can be used for feature detection and data compression.

Further reading:

- [neural networks and non linear principal compinent analysis](http://www.nlpca.org/) with a nice  example of auto associative network.
- [difference between replicator networks and autoencoders](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/difference-replicator-neural-network-vs-autoencoder)
- [Approximate realization of identity mappings by three‐layer neural networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229595818_Approximate_realization_of_identity_mappings_by_three-layer_neural_networks) abstract of an article that summarizes properties of the hidden layer

Comment: Aren't they called "autoencoders" instead of "replicators"?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson aren't autoencoders are more general concept compared to the replicator ? I think that the replicator always has to replicate 1 to 1 its input at a certain layer of the net (i.e. identity) while autoencoders map themselves to the input, but not necessarily with a 1 to 1 layer. There's a link to an SE contribution about this difference.

Answer (score 5):

It's the same as it is in Algebra.

An [identity map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/what-does-identity-map-id-mean) or [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) gives out exactly what it got.

When they say:

*h*(x<sub>l</sub>) = x<sub>l</sub>

They mean *h* is an identity mapping / function. If you give it x<sub>l</sub> it will give you back x<sub>l</sub>.

*h* might be something else but once they say it's *h*(x<sub>l</sub>) = x<sub>l</sub> then it's an identity map / function.

I don't see anything here to suggest the meaning changes once you're in a neural network context.

It might seem pointless to have a map or function that gives you back what you gave it, and it kind of is. The need for them arises from using a system (an architecture, framework, or whatever) that expects a map/function in a step that actually isn't needed in this case. Rather than build a new system for this case we use an identity map/function that lets us reuse the old system.

It's the same kind of thinking that invented [0](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696269/151778), the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), the [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type), and some of the reasons I pass in empty collections. The system expects something but you need that something to be nothing. These constructs give the nothing a form that wont break the system.